# prevent OSX menu bar from showing in node webkit kiosk mode

Tags: node.js, macos, node-webkit, kiosk

i've got a node webkit (nw v0.12.3) app which opens in kiosk mode

```
var nw = require('nw.gui');
var win - nw.Window.get();
win.enterKioskMode();
```

this works fine except that when the mouse hovers to the top of the screen in OSX the Mac menu bar slides down. Is there any way to prevent this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a third party developer, you [cannot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) hide the menu bar because of Apple limitations.